# How to collect bounces in postfix

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

This is related to this question:

[linux - Ways to get a bounceback report for my newsletter application? - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/20550/ways-to-get-a-bounceback-report-for-my-newsletter-application)

Let's say I'm generating email addresses like this when I send out newsletters to identify bounces and unsubscribe them from my newsletter: bounce-123456789@example.com

I assume I'd use this in the return-path, right?

Then how would I set it up in postfix to collect all these addresses prefixed with "bounce-" into one mailbox?

Finally, I've heard people mention a soft bounce vs. a hard bounce.  Can someone explain the different and how they should be counted to know when to permanently remove someone from an email newsletter?

Comment: Note that an email address that includes the word "bounce" may also be viewed as "yuck"... (spam)—that being said, if you can stick your own `Message-Id` in your header, it has to be sent back and that would be enough to check who's who.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The exact answer to your question (handling the `bounce-xxx@example.com` address) depends on how your server is configured to receive mail.  If `example.com` is the virtual domain the best you can do is collect the messages in the `bounce@example.com` mailbox (assuming `recipient_delimiter = -`).

If `example.com` is the locally delivered domain for the server (mail is delivered to actual system accounts) then you can add a `.forward` file to the home directory of the `bounce` user, which delivers to a program that parses the bounce information and records it in a database or file.  See `man local` for more info on the `.forward` format and how to deliver to a program.

What we do, since we send messages for a large number of domains, is use `bounces.example.com` as our VERP domain.  This domain needs to be added to `relay_domains`.  Create `/etc/postfix/transport_maps` with this content:

```
bounces.example.com             bulkbounce:
```

Then append a line similar to this to `/etc/postfix/master.cf`:

```
bulkbounce   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  user=nobody argv=/usr/local/bin/bounce_handler.py ${recipient}
```

The `bounce_handler.py` script accepts the VERP address as its command line option, parses it and makes the necessary database updates to record the bounce.

Comment: Ooh, I like the idea of using the recipient delimeter to group them.  Typically a + is used right?  I think that will work great, thanks!

Comment: Can you show what `bounce_handler.py` would look like?

Answer (score 18):

Actually, Instyle's answer is very difficult to implement if you want to support many different domains and it is wrong because:

a) With his example of `transport_maps`, all the emails sent to that domain are sent to that specific service without any regard to whether the emails are bounced emails or not. Since it uses a specific domain name, it should indeed only be bounced emails... but it cannot be guaranteed that way.

b) The data sent to your script is the email itself and not the bounce message. In other words, your code may have no idea why the email was bounced (i.e. local bounce will send you the original email only.)

---

The correct way to do that setup in postfix is to use the bounce notification class.

1) In **/etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
notify_classes = bounce
bounce_notice_recipient = bounces@example.com
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport_maps
```

2) In **/etc/postfix/transport_maps**

```
# when you make changes to this file, run:
#   sudo postmap /etc/postfix/transport_maps
bounces@example.com bulkbounce:
```

As you can see, we now tell postfix to use `bounces@example.com` whenever an email gets bounced. Then in the transport map, to use `bulkbounce` as the service to handle any email address to `bounces@example.com`.

Finally you can define `bulkbounce` with your script:

3) In **/etc/postfix/master.cf**

```
bulkbounce unix -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FRq user=bounce argv=/home/bounce/bin/snapbounce --sender ${sender} --recipient ${recipient}
```

This script requires you to have a user. `nobody` is a good choice too. If you want to have a specific user, you can create it with:

```
useradd bounce
```

Without the script in `master.cf`, the emails are sent to the bulkbounce account. So if you have a script that parses emails from files, this would work without the `transport_maps` and `master.cf` changes.

---

From a comment below:

> fyi - re: double bounces...
>   if you're modifying the return address (VERP address such as `user+id@fromdomain.com`, then you will want to comment out the line in `main.cf` for the `bounce_notice_recipient`, if you're interested in parsing the `+id` bounce only in your script.

Comment: Using your way I somehow receive the bounce twice, once with bounce+id@... and once with bounce@... from double-bounce - (the user bounce does not actualy exist on the system - as I do not intent to 'save' these emails). The email is sent with a Return-path of bounce+id@...  Any idea what I am missing ?

Comment: @RVandersteen I'm not too sure why you'd get it twice. The one with `+id@` may be an envelop of some kind?

Comment: When I use our default 'from' address - the bounce still gets sent to bounce@example.com and originalfrom@example.com (no return path added anymore)

Comment: Seems that I am wrong about the 'original from' it is the email listed in /etc/aliases under root (postmaster -> root -> originalfrom@example.com) which also receives the bounce

Comment: somehow once Sender: MAILER-DAEMON,
Recipient: bounce@example.com and once Sender: double-bounce@example.com,
Recipient: bounce@example.com (Note that we have a send only postfix)

Comment: @RVandersteen If you have double bouncing emails, you probably want to search about that. I suppose you did not notice the problem before you tried to install my code here, correct? One thing I could think of is that the transport happens at the wrong place in your case.

Comment: I've been at this for days without finding any usefull information on the matter. Anyhow, I've posted a question here https://serverfault.com/questions/883805/postfix-bounce-sent-twice-double-bounce

Comment: For future reference, adding the notify_classes does not change the behaviour of the MTA sending the bounce message to the FROM/Return Path. It adds behaviour on top of it (sends it also to the notify_bounce_recipient). This is why I had double mails coming in. Which answers my question(s) above

Comment: fyi - re: double bounces..if you're modifying the return address (VERP address such as 'user+id@fromdomain.com', then you will want to comment out the line in main.cf for the 'bounce_notice_recipient', if you're interested in parsing the +id bounce only in your script.

Comment: I don't think the double bounces is due to VERP. `Return-Path` is to inform the author that the message bounced, whereas `notify_classes` is to notify the administrator of the mail server. It is not a 2nd bounce/email per se. I feel this better explains the behavior observed.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern mailing list software already knows how to handle VERP messages if the MTA is properly configured to pass them back to the mailing list software. In the case of [GNU Mailman](http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/) you should checkout the [FAQ](http://wiki.list.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=8683535) page aptly named "How do I use VERP with a - delimiter (Postfix recipient_delimiter)?".

If you're making your own custom newsletter software to handle this you should ask yourself why you're re-inventing the wheel instead of using existing applications that can handle the task simply and easily for you already.

Comment: Yep, I'm making my own newsletter software.  There is a good reason!

Comment: Then you should look at having it use VERP to handle bounces properly.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I think you're right VERP is the standard solution here, although it appears it's only useful to identify the sender and recipient.  In this case we need to also identify the particular message which went out that caused the bounce, so I believe we'll have to do a custom solution with our own ID in the address.  I think the solution mentioned below using a recipient delimeter will let us group them together in one bounce account. Thanks for the response though I appreciate the help!

Comment: Insyte's solution is just a modified VERP at it's core. You just need to make sure that it provides enough of a unique identifier for your bounce handler to identify it. In most mailing list software that is the email address, but could be anything since you're designing your own.