# postfix bounce configuration

Tags: postfix, email-bounces

What I have is:

1. Windows server generating emails with own app and sending them to relay server (2) - this works fine
2. Relay server that sends emails received from (1) - CentOS - working fine

What I need is to additionally configure CentOS postfix to send bounce messages to Windows server (to work on them using own app on specified port).
I tried to add in /etc/postfix/transport line:

```
test.pl        bounced:[12.34.56.78]:29990
```

and run

```
postmap /etc/postfix/transport
```

but I have no idea what I should do more to make it work.

In maillog I have:

```
Mar  6 12:00:22 ubuntu postfix/qmgr[1633]: 9CBB260899: from=<root@ubuntu>, size=197, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar  6 12:00:22 ubuntu postfix/qmgr[1633]: warning: connect to transport private/bounced: No such file or directory
Mar  6 12:00:22 ubuntu postfix/error[1744]: 9CBB260899: to=<a@test.pl>, relay=none, delay=1890, delays=1890/0/0/0.01, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
```

Comment: Do you have `transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport` in your `main.conf`?  Have you restarted or reloaded postfix since making these changes?

Comment: Yes, I have this line in main.cf. Yes, I've runned postfix reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have I done to make it work:

1. Written a python script to send standard input through TCP to bounce server (fixed IP and port)
2. Added a line to postfix master.cf file, to send bounce emails to python script:

   ```
   bounced unix - n n - - pipe user=bounce argv=/etc/postfix/mailpipe.py
   ```
3. Added a line to /etc/services and corresponding postfix services file:

   ```
   bounced     23232/tcp           # bounce
   ```
4. Made transport file for postfix:

   ```
   domain.com          bounced:[12.34.56.78]:23232
   ```
5. "Compiled" postmap transport file:

   ```
   postmap /etc/postfix/transport
   ```
6. Made user bounce and added it to group postfix
7. Restarted by:

   ```
   postfix reload
   ```

Answer (score 1):

In transport, you normally only have 4 options. Local, Virtual, Relay or Default. If you're going to create another, you'll need to define what it does in the master.cf file. That's why you are getting file not found errors. You've told it to send it to bounced, but not created bounced.

You should probably have a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/48326/how-to-collect-bounces-in-postfix) to start you off in the right direction.

Comment: That helped me a little, but didn't give the resolution. I'll put the answer myself.