# Postfix: Script to difference hard vs soft bounces

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-bounces

I followed the steps mentioned in the forum - [how to collect bounces](https://serverfault.com/questions/48326/how-to-collect-bounces-in-postfix) for triggering a script upon a bounce receipt. Now, I would like to classify the bounce depending on the status. It would be deferred/delivered/etc.. This would categorize them as soft . vs hard bounce. Any idea on how this can be achieved?

I looked at the [pipe command attributes](http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html) and dont find a {status} argument to the script that we execute.

Below is my postfix master config extract:

```
bounces unix - n n - - pipe
   flags=FRqx user=bounce argv=/usr/share/postfix/bounce.sh ${sender} ${recipient} ${mailbox} ${original_recipient} ${recipient}
smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
   -o content_filter=bounces:dummy
```

Transport.maps:

```
bounces@teleduce.tech bounces
```

My end goal is to classify hard vs soft bounces.

Regards