# How do I get Postfix to run a script every time there is a outgoing delivery error?

Tags: postfix, scripting, hook

I would like postfix to run a external php script (a hook) every time there is a outgoing delivery error.

For example, my webserver sends out emails and sometimes the recipients mailbox is full or nonexistent:

> (host mx2.seznam.cz[77.75.76.32] said: 450 5.1.1 Mailbox is currently
>   disabled. (in reply to RCPT TO command))

I would like to capture those errors through a script and notify my user that he needs to update his email address in our system.

Is it possible to get postfix to dump all of this information (email address, SMTP error) into a external script as they happen?

Thank you.

Comment: That sounds like handling a bounce. There is an answer here for that: https://serverfault.com/questions/48326/how-to-collect-bounces-in-postfix/735721#735721

Comment: @AlexisWilke thank you for that link! It does work wonderfully for hard errors, however I still can't find a way of passing deferred emails to a script:

`status=deferred (connect to email.bg[89.25.48.10]:25: Connection timed out)`

Comment: Well... the master.cf line uses `bulkbounce` in my example there. Did you look into using `defer` as well? (point 3 in my answer) I never tried that on a deferred message since that will either work later or fail with a bounce anyway.

Comment: @AlexisWilke thank you for your inputs. I ended up doing another way (check my answer).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up rerouting rsyslog maillog notifications via UDP to a simple php daemon for processing and doing all the magic there.

The bounce-daemon.php is controlled by monit, so it's always up and running.

rsyslog.conf:

```
# Forward postfix logs via UDP 
mail.*                                                  @127.0.0.1:55515
```

bounce-daemon.php:

```
$socket = stream_socket_server("udp://127.0.0.1:55515", $errno, $errstr, STREAM_SERVER_BIND);
if (!$socket) {
    die("$errstr ($errno)");
}

do {

    //  echo "Waiting for data... ";
    $pkt = stream_socket_recvfrom($socket, 10000, 0, $peer);

    // do processing here
    echo "$pkt\n";

} while ($pkt !== false);
```

Comment: I'm contemplating between yours vs this https://serverfault.com/questions/48326/how-to-collect-bounces-in-postfix/735721#735721, have you came across before?