# Postfix without queues?

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, email-server

I would like to use Postfix as an MTA to deliver emails that I create locally using a Python SMTP client. But I would like to handle the re-sending of emails manually, rather than using Postfix's automatic queues. I also want to get the status codes from the destination server back to Python through my local Postfix. Is this possible?

EDIT: See comment below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds you don't want to rely on a MTA at all, but want to handle everything within your own code. If that is the case, don't use postfix as the MTA...

But I *think* that if you set [`bounce_queue_lifetime`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html)  to `0` only a single delivery attempt will be made.

It might be useful to create your own [`bounce_service_name`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) to handle delivery failures instead of the using the default postfix [`bounce`](http://www.postfix.org/bounce.8.html) daemon, if you don't want to parse the (non-)delivery status log and/or bounce messages.

Comment: And also https://serverfault.com/q/48326/546643

Comment: Thanks for these. I guess what I _really_ want is a simple SMTP implementation that isn't a static proxy, but that uses the email destination to determine the server to contact. It seems so simple, but I can't find any Python repo that does that. Even fancy packages like aiosmtpd don't accomplish this, they include a shell handler that's a static proxy.